# Compose border and clip artifacts

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I have this UI element

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        ...
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        .border(1.dp, borderColor, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        .drawWithCache {
            val topGradient = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = listOf(topBgGradientColor, bottomBgGradientColor)
            )
            onDrawBehind {
                drawRect(topGradient)
            }
        },
) {
```

You can notice that gradient background is visible a little outside of border. Why does it happen and how to fix it or is this Compose rendering bug?

Tried both emulator and real device but the same result

[image]

**Updated:**

temporary fixed it like this:

```
// call it first
.border(1.dp, borderColor, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
// increased from 16 to 18 to remove background outside border
.clip(RoundedCornerShape(18.dp))
```

Comment: Are you applying a size modifier?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes  `.constrainAs(bg) {
                    width = Dimension.value(dp = 39.dp)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints`, why does it matter anyway?

Comment: Did you try if you have the same issue applying a static `size` modifier like `size(50.dp,200.dp)` after the `border` modifier removing the constraint?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti tried it, still the same issue even with fixed size